# Annotating a pgfplots graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I tried the solution proposed in : [How can/should I include annotated images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/how-can-should-i-include-annotated-images)

However, the coordinates don't match with the coordinates I used when plotting the diagrams (data coordinates). For example, I have a mesh generated by a python program and matplotlib and I want to annotate it, using the same coordinates I used when plotting the data.

Let's say there is a node in the mesh at coordinates `(2,3)`. I'd like to be able to annotate it using `\node at (2,3) {text};`

Comment: This can be done very conveniently using PGFplots. Could you include a sample image in your question?

Comment: @Jake I tried to use the python package matplotlib2tikz, which produces a pgfplots plot. The result is fine, but the coordinates still seem scaled.

http://pastebin.com/W6dyawE4

This is the output created by the package. At the bottom, I'm creating two nodes which don't show up at the specified coordinates. Any idea?

Comment: Related (for including an image and referring to its coordinate system): [Image with axis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38632/image-with-axis)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to refer to the axis coordinates of a pgfplots `axis`, you'll need to put the TikZ commands (like `\draw`, `\node`, or `\path`) *inside* the `axis` environment, and you'll need to use the  `axis cs:` coordinate system.

In your example, you could say

```
...
\addplot [red, mark=*, mark options={draw=black}, only marks]
coordinates {
(-0.05,0.25) 
};

\node at (axis cs:1,1) [anchor=north east] {test};
\node at (axis cs:0,0) [anchor=south west] {test};
\end{axis}
...
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this works like a charm. You might wonder why I need plotting at all, as these meshes could be created using simple \draw and \fill commands.
However, these meshes can get really complicated. Maybe I will implement another backend for my python program to just create \fill and \draw commands. For now, this solution is perfect though.

Comment: @triggerfish: Glad it helps! Would you mind editing your question and question title to more accurately reflect what the question turned out to be about (something like "Annotating a pgfplots graph", since you're not actually using an external PDF)?

Comment: @Jake I'm a bit "lost in search": I've got my data points and axes correctly labeled; I'd just want to add `R² = 0.61` "somewhere" in the plot; how best to do that?