# pgfplots error using matlab2tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I am trying to plot a matlab figure in latex file. so i use this 
[matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz) function.

It works really well, until I try to add some customised text on the figure before converting it to tikz file, and when I try to build my latex file, it say error something like

```
Package pgfplots Error: the arguments of [mesh/rows=2,mesh/cols=0] assume 0 p 
oints, but I got actually N = 1 points! The data matrix appears to be incomplete
```

The problem is gone when I remove the text from the matlab file.

Can anyone help me?

I can't provide the real data here since it's too long, but I can give you an example.

Imagine I am plotting this

```
syms x
ezplot(sin(6*x))
```

Then, once it is plotted in the matlab, I go to `Insert>Text Box` and add some text on the figure.

Then, I will run this code

```
matlab2tikz('test.tikz', 'height', '\figureheight', 'width', '\figurewidth')
```

However, when I put this code in latex

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\centering
\input{Chapter4/Figs/test.tikz}
\caption[Surface force calibration]{Surface force calibration with small loads (100g, 200g and 300g)} 
\label{fig:irfan} 
\end{figure}
```

it is saying the error.

Comment: When a text box is included in the Matlab figure, I get the following message from `matlab2tikz`: `Warning: Don't know class 'scribe.textbox'. Default handling.` Comparing the output of the function with and without a text box, it seems that the default handling goes wrong. For example, I don't see why a textbox would be drawn as a three dimensional plot with `\addplot3`. The text of the box is not included in the `.tikz` file, either. I suggest checking https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz/issues and filing a feature request / bug report if the issue has not been reported yet.

Comment: For the record, the beginning of my `pgfplots` error message is the same as yours. The message continues: `or overcomplete!? [Use mesh/check=false to disable this message].`

Comment: That 'Don't know class 'scribe.textbox'` warning crops up as part of [#175 Cannot export a loglog plot to tikz](https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz/issues/175). But a separate issue probably needs to be created there.

Comment: @MikeRenfro it didnot mention how to solve it, and I asked question there but gets no reply. can anyone help me please

Comment: The solution is to file a bug with the `matlab2tikz` author on GitHub about this specific problem.

Comment: You could try circumventing the issue by not adding the text on the Matlab side, but by editing the `.tikz` file produced by `matlab2tikz` and manually adding a text label. See [Annotating a pgfplots graph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54088)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in matlab2tikz.