# how to add labels to x and y axis in figure environment

Tags: graphics, labels

I was able to include a .eps file in my latex document in the following way :

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm, height = 6cm]{x.eps}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to add labels for the x and y axis (the image has been imported from a plotting software without the x and y axis labels) in latex. Is there a way to accomplish this in latex ? I tried using tikz but I was not able to get desired results.

Comment: You should take a look at the `psfrag` and `psfragx` packages.

Comment: Have a look at [Image with axis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38632/35864) and [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/35864).

Comment: @moewe - I did have a look at that post and even implemented it. But I was not able to add x and y axis labels. Specifically, I was not able to get them to appear in the right place or align with the image.

Comment: Well, in that case it would have been much more helpful if you had shown us what you tried so far and how it didn't work for you.

Comment: Welcome! Did you see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/) answer to the second question moewe linked to? Since that gives you a grid enabling you to read suitable coordinates off, I'm not sure what the issue with alignment might be?

Comment: @cfr - Thank you for that. I did notice it but did not pay that much attention. I will get down to trying it out right away. I will edit my post to include what I have tried.