# pgfplots graphics plot in XeLaTeX

Tags: pgfplots, xetex

The following code is copied from [an answer by Christian Feuersänger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38634/47217):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false, axis on top, axis equal image]
\addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=96,ymin=0,ymax=96] {Dad64};
\node at (axis cs:49,30) [
    circle,
    draw,
    red,
    thick,
    minimum size=3ex,
    pin={[pin edge=thick]-10:Nose}
] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false, axis on top, axis equal image, width=6cm]
\addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=96,ymin=0,ymax=96] {Dad64};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When built with pdflatex, I get the correct result (same as in Christian's answer), but when I build it using xelatex, I get the following incorrect result:

[image: Output]

I really need XeLaTeX. How can I get the expected result?

Comment: works okay for me. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I'm still on TeX Live 2017, and I had hoped to be able to postpone the upgrade to TeX Live 2019 just a little longer..

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: This induced me to finally take the bull by the horns and upgrade to TeX Live 2019. Now the example above works in XeLaTeX as well. Many thanks for giving me the courage!

Comment: It doesn't need so much courage:  it you have the disk space you can always install the newer tex live beside the older. I have a number of versions and can switch if needed.